# How can I save a .bmp in racket?

Tags: racket

I have created a bitmap in drracket, and I would like to save it as a .bmp on my hard drive.

```
#lang racket
(require racket/draw)

(define test-bitmap
  (let* ((target (make-bitmap 60 30))
         (dc (new bitmap-dc% [bitmap target])))
    (send dc set-font (make-font #:size 14 #:family 'roman
                                 #:weight 'bold))
    (send dc set-text-foreground "blue")
    (send dc draw-text "test" 5 1)
    target))

(send test-bitmap save-file "test.bmp" 'bmp)
```

When I run this code, drracket reports that "*save-file in bitmap%: kind saving not yet implemented: 'bmp*" If I use 'png as the kind in the save-file message, the file saves correctly (though with significant visual artifacts).

The [documentation for bitmap%](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/bitmap_.html) lists 'bmp as a valid kind for this operation.

Is this actually unimplemented, or am I making a silly mistake?

Comment: What kind of "significant visual artifacts"? If it's a chequered background, it's because you didn't set a background colour and some programs will display chequers to signify a transparent background.

Comment: The actual image that I'm trying to save is a grid of text in various colors against a white background, and in many cases there are greenish outlines of the text.

Comment: Odd!  Can you put up sample code somewhere for folks to investigate?  There should be no visual artifacts when saving to `.png`.

Comment: Sure, I'll trim my code down to the essentials and post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, BMP files can only be loaded, not saved. See [racket/draw/private/bitmap.rkt](http://git.racket-lang.org/plt/blob/HEAD:/collects/racket/draw/private/bitmap.rkt) for more details.

Yes, that does make the documentation for `save-file` erroneous. I really haven't spotted anything in the source code that would suggest that `save-file` would actually support `bmp`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I can live with png, I suppose.